# Add array of subtitles to UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

How to different subtitle to each row in `UITableView`

```
subArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Red", @"Blue", @"Green" , @"Yellow", nil];

cell.detailTextLabel.text=[self->subArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

return [self->subArray count];
```

This is what i have done but for some reason i cant see the text in the `UITabelView` unless i change the code to `cell.textlabel.text`.

Comment: Make sure you are using correct type of UITableViewCell.

Comment: do you want to display the text on cell simply?

Comment: @Ujjwal yes the code below sorted out my problem but i thought since the subtitle was on the right in the storyboard then that would be where the array text would be placed? However for some reason it seems to be on the left.

Comment: @mitesh : try the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you have set your cell's `detailTextLabel`, you still need to set its style to one of three `enum` values which display the `detailTextLabel` (found [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UITableViewCellStyle)).

If you want to add the subtitle on the right, the corresponding `enum` value is `UITableViewCellStyleValue1`. In code this is how you need to initialise your cell:

```
[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle: UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier: identifier]
```

Where `identifier` is your cell's reuseIdentifier.

Answer (score 1):

set `UITableViewCell` style to `UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle`

e.g.

```
 if(!cell)
   {
       cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
   }
```

Comment: Thank you that worked however i expected the subtitle to be on the right side since that's where it is in the storyboard?

Comment: for that set `UITableViewCellStyleValue1`

Answer (score 0):

Your initialization needs to be changed to this:

```
cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle 
                                   reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
cell.detailTextLabel.text=[subArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue2 reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
```

Try this.